# Микропитон из строки в байты

Tags: micropython

MicroPython v1.18-23-g7d71ae25e-custom
Имеется строка `'\xF0\xF1\xF2'`, как преобразовать в байты `b'\xF0\xF1\xF2'`?
`bytes('\xF0\xF1\xF2','ascii')` и `bytes('\xF0\xF1\xF2','cp-1251')` дает такой же результат как и `bytes('\xF0\xF1\xF2','utf-8')`. То есть юникод `b'\xc3\xb0\xc3\xb1\xc3\xb2'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На обычном Python работает вариант через кодировку `"latin"`:

```
>>> bytes('\xF0\xF1\xF2', encoding="latin")
b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'
```

На micropython это не работает, пока лучшее что смог придумать - брать код каждого символа функцией `ord`, потом полученный набор чисел преобразовать в байтовую строку:

```
>>> text = '\xF0\xF1\xF2'
>>> bytes(map(ord, text))
b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'
# Или через выражение-генератор вместо функции map
>>> bytes(ord(char) for char in text)
b'\xf0\xf1\xf2'
```

Comment: Спасибо работает